# List all devices, partitions and volumes in Powershell

Tags: list, powershell, device

I have multiple volumes (as nearly everybody nowadays): on Windows they end up specified as C:, D: and so on. How do I list these all like on a Unix machine with "ls /mnt/" with Powershell?

Comment: get-psdrive 
will return this
Name  Provider  Root         CurrentLocation
----  --------  ----         ---------------
A   FileSystem A:Alias  Alias
C   FileSystem C:\           scripts

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To get all of the file system drives, you can use the following command:

```
gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

`gdr` is an alias for [`Get-PSDrive`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849796.aspx), which includes all of the "virtual drives" for the registry, etc.

Comment: This also include the CD ROM which I am not sure is desired in all use cases keep that in mind guys.

Comment: or you could also use Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk

Comment: This also does not include mount points such as iSCSI disks.

Answer (score 47):

```
Get-Volume
```

You will get:
DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, FileSystem, DriveType, HealthStatus, SizeRemaining and Size.

Comment: Get-Volume appears to be available only on Windows-Server 2012 and Windows-Server 2016.

Comment: Get-Volume worked for me running powershell 5.1. Perhaps they made this standard in recent years/recent updates. This answer should get more attention.

Comment: This is now the right answer.  The answers using Get-PDDrive are for older versions of powershell

Comment: If you want details, there is Get-Drive and Get-Partition, that can be piped for everything. Get-Drive | Get-Partition

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: Also worked for me in Windows 11. This is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 15):

On Windows Powershell:

```
Get-PSDrive 
[System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives()
wmic diskdrive
wmic volume
```

Also the utility dskwipe: http://smithii.com/dskwipe

```
dskwipe.exe -l
```

Comment: To tag on, you can also include a flag from another answer `-PSProvider:'FileSystem'` to display only file systems.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, on Unix you use `mount`, not `ls /mnt`: many things are not mounted in `/mnt`.

Anyhow, there's the `mountvol` DOS command, which continues to work in Powershell, and there's the Powershell-specific `Get-PSDrive`.

Answer (score 5):

Run command:

```
Get-PsDrive -PsProvider FileSystem
```

For more info see:

- [PsDrive Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-6)
- [PSProvider Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psprovider?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 4):

Though this isn't 'powershell' specific... you can easily list the drives and partitions using diskpart, list volume

```
PS C:\Dev> diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: Box

DISKPART> list volume

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
Volume 1         C = System   NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
Volume 2     G   C = Box      NTFS   Partition    244 GB  Healthy    Boot
Volume 3     H   D = Data     NTFS   Partition    687 GB  Healthy
Volume 4     E   System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy
```

Comment: is it possible to get Volume ## using powershell? (For windows 7)

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty old, but I found following worth noting:

```
PS N:\> (measure-command {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk|select -property deviceid|%{$_.deviceid}|out-host}).totalmilliseconds
...
928.7403
PS N:\> (measure-command {gdr -psprovider 'filesystem'|%{$_.name}|out-host}).totalmilliseconds
...
169.474
```

Without filtering properties, on my test system, 4319.4196ms to 1777.7237ms. Unless I need a PS-Drive object returned, I'll stick with WMI.

EDIT:
 I think we have a winner: 
PS N:> (measure-command {[System.IO.DriveInfo]::getdrives()|%{$_.name}|out-host}).to‌​talmilliseconds
110.9819

Answer (score 2):

To list drives:

```
fsutil fsinfo drives
```

Is also supported by CMD and requires no elevation nor extra 3rd-parties.

Answer (score 1):

We have multiple volumes per drive (some are mounted on subdirectories on the drive). This code shows a list of the mount points and volume labels. Obviously you can also extract free space and so on:

```
gwmi win32_volume|where-object {$_.filesystem -match "ntfs"}|sort {$_.name} |foreach-object {
  echo "$(echo $_.name) [$(echo $_.label)]"
}
```

Comment: For PWSH 7, that would be `Get-CimInstance Win32_Volume` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the device is present, but not (yet) mounted, this helps:

```
Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly -InstanceId SCSI*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find the "total" disk size on a drive as well.

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName yourhostname Win32_LogicalDisk |
  foreach-object {
    write " $($_.Caption) $('{0:N2}' -f ($_.Size/1gb)) GB total, $('{0:N2}' -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)) GB free "
}
```

Comment: this seems like a VERY minor variation of one of the previous Answers. what is the benefit to yours that is not in the other?

Comment: This will work with PWSH 7 as the previous answer wont...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a way of doing this as part of their `az vm repair` scripts (see: [Repair a Windows VM by using the Azure Virtual Machine repair commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/repair-windows-vm-using-azure-virtual-machine-repair-commands)).

It is available under MIT license at: https://github.com/Azure/repair-script-library/blob/51e60cf70bba38316394089cee8e24a9b1f22e5f/src/windows/common/helpers/Get-Disk-Partitions.ps1

Answer (score -2):

You can also do it on the CLI with

```
net use
```

Comment: `net use` will only display mounted network devices.